# dask distributed exception reporting in progress bar

Tags: python, exception, dask, dask-distributed

I'm posting this on StackOverflow as I'm not sure whether it is a bug or a misinterpretation of something I am observing.

I am submitting a function repeatedly to a local cluster of 4 workers with different parameter values as follows within JupyterLab 2.1.5 using dask distributed 2.19.0 and Python 3.7.6 on Ubuntu 18.04:

```py
# x is a numpy.ndarray
x_future = client.scatter(x, broadcast=True)
future_list = [client.submit(func, x_future, i) for i in range(x.shape[1])]
distributed.progress(future_list)
```

I've observed the progress bar seemingly stop updating in the midst of processing and change appearance in what seems to a visual indication of an exception raised during execution of the submitted function:

[image]

The status of the futures in `future_list` after the above occurs all appear to be `finished`, however, and I'm able to retrieve results from them. Moreover, if I run the function above serially for all of the indicated parameter values (i.e., in a `for` loop rather than with `distributed`), I only observe a `RuntimeWarning` raised by the function for some parameter values (which is expected given what the function is supposed to do) but never any exception. What, then, is the above change in progress bar appearance supposed to indicate?

Comment: Do you mind to add a [mcve](/help/mcve)? It seems like a perfect case for an issue on github

Comment: What's the error from the failed future?

Comment: None of the futures appear to be in a failed state.